# I am using navbar-expand-md so it will show mobile menu on sm screens <768px..But i want to show mobile menu on sm at <=768px

Tags: html, css

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Lj0o4RNA9EuQFin2Jf16_Ec6KvVMKLe?usp=sharing)

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    left: -75%;
    transition: height 0s ease;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.show {
    left: 0;
    transition: left 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .navbar-toggler.collapsed~.navbar-collapse {
    transition: left 500ms ease-in-out;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 85px;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->


<header style="background-color:#F4DF4EFF;" class="sticy-top">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-main">

        <?php
          $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
          $custom_logo_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id ,  'full' );
          $custom_logo_url = $custom_logo_data[0];
        ?>
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $custom_logo_url );  ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );  ?>" style="width:80px;height:70px;" />
          <!-- <span ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x "  ></i></span> -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <div style="color:black;">
                <?php
              wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ,
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto', 
                    
              ) );
            ?>
              </div>
            </ul>

          </div>



      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want to show mobile menu on sm  at <=768px ..But i get mobile menu at <768..
(or)As i am using navbar-expand-md so that nav bar collpase at <768px but i want it to collpase at <=768px and  slide navbar from left at <=768.. I think i want to do some modifications in my css and code to get the result..Please help me...

Thank a lot in advance